# Conditional sum in R studio according to different city names

Tags: r, sum, conditional-statements

I have a data set with 3 columns: the first has names of cities, the second has dates and the third data for water quality. I have ordered my data according to the city names and then the dates and now I am trying to sum the data of the water quality for each city separately. Do you know how I can do that in r studio?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the tidyverse  package you can group by the city and then summarise the information adding up all the data from water_quality

```
library(tidyverse)
# im using this data set
ds <- tibble(city = "a", wq = 1) %>%
  add_row( city = "a", wq = 1) %>%
  add_row( city = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b"), wq = c(.5, .2, .5, .7, 1.2))

#you're interested in this part
ds %>% group_by(city) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(wq))
```

this is the output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  city    sum
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a       3.2
2 b       1.4
3 c       0.5
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That solved my problem.